# jcarousel issue with last item

Tags: jquery, css, jcarousel

I am using the jquery jcarousel and am having trouble with it. When I scroll to the last item there always seems to be a little bit left over that means another scroll.

An example can be seen below:

http://gordonhouse.gumpshen.com/women/rings.aspx

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the margin to `margin:0;` to your `li.first` and `li.middle` and make it global

```
ul.promo li {
    margin: 0 14px 0 0;
}
```